# iPhone 6 Autolayout issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, xcode7

A year ago i created an iphone app with xcode 6, i addded the autolayout, everything works fine on iphone 5 and iphone 6, but earlier i created a new app which is a duplicate of the older app, i added also autolayout but nothing works normally on iphone 6, the size of images, buttons are small however i added the @1X and the @2x size. i used the sames ressources as the older app.

The difference between older app and the newest one is that before i use ModalViewControllers but now i use ContainerViewController and switching between views.

I did not understand from where it comes the problem.

This is a screen shot of older app on iphone 6

[image]
And This is a screen shot of the newest app on iphone 6

[image]

What can be the problem?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear from your question what your problem actually is (both screenshots look fine), but I guess your issue is that on the second one the elements are somewhat smaller in proportion to the screen, is that it?

If so, that's because the first one is running in iPhone 5 (4" screen) emulation mode, just scaled up to take more space on the larger screen, while the second one runs in native iPhone 6 mode. The views are actually the same size as on an iPhone 5, they just take less space in proportion to the size of the screen (that's the goal of a larger screen).

Check the SDK version the app is build against, as well as the presence of a Launch Screen XIB, I believe those are the triggers for switching to the native mode.

If you want (some) UI elements to be larger on larger screens, you can use height or width constraints with multipliers, but fonts are trickier, you'll need to handle that in code.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the problem was the Launch Screen XIB, i remove it and i used Default-568h@2x.png,  and now it works fine on iphone 5 and iphone 6

Comment: It depends on your definition of "works fine"... It is actually just running in iPhone 5 emulation mode on the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus, which means everything is just scaled up, and users don't get much benefit of the larger screen, everything's just bigger...